# aggregate by groups and report in sas

Tags: sas, aggregate, display

I've gotten the data I need and simply want to present it better, more like a pivot table in excel. The current code, that gives me the right value for freq is as follows:

```
proc means data = d sum;  
vars mth age freq;  
class mth age;  
run;
```

Variables "mth" and "age"are categories (7 groups each) and the goal was to get the sum of the variable "freq" for all of the intersections between "mth" and "age".  That was successful and the results are formatted as follows:

```
mth  age NObs Variable Sum
1     1   20  mth      20
              age      20
              freq     40
      2   30  mth      30
              age      30
              freq     65
...    ...       ... 
7     1   25  mth      25
              age      25
              freq     48
```

Again, the freq summation is correct with my code, i just want to display the results as follows:

```
  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
                         (<- column sum totals) 
1                40  40  (<- intersection sums for freq) 
2
...
7
```

proc sql isnt playing nice and im not sure thats what to use anyways.  Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PROC MEANS` isn't really the right tool: you want `PROC TABULATE`.

```
proc tabulate data=have;
  class mth age;
  var freq;
  tables mth,(all age)*freq*sum;
run;
```

Something along those lines.  `all` gives you column totals, you could do the same thing before the `,` to get row totals.

Comment: close enough that I was able to figure it out.  I thought maybe proc tabulate but hadnt used it before.  thanks

Comment: any way to get one of the categorical variables to display in descending order?

Comment: `order` options on class statement, presumably.